# Swagger Swashbuckle abstract class documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have Web API request model with property:

```
public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
```

Feature is an abstract class. I'll have many classes derived from it:

```
public abstract class Feature
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ImageFeature : Feature
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously Swashbuckle only recognizes `Feature` properties and generates documentation accordingly. How do I explicitly declare possible implementations of `Feature` class so that Swashbuckle generate proper docs? Is there some attribute I could use, something like:

```
[SwaggerResponseType(typeof(ImageFeature))]
[SwaggerResponseType(typeof(AnotherFeature))]
public abstract class Feature
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : [swagger inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862407/swagger-inheritance-and-composition)

Comment: I use this approach - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397349/how-do-i-include-subclasses-in-swagger-api-documentation-using-swashbuckle

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this one:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#!/InheritanceTest/InheritanceTest_Get

[image]

And here is the code behind that controller:
https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/911bf68e0cf6af3ee5d8278e6dd988eda8c4dc8d/Swagger_Test/Controllers/InheritanceTestController.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Swagger_Test.Controllers
{
    public abstract class Feature
    {
        /// <summary>We all need a Title</summary>
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class ImageFeature : Feature
    {
        /// <summary>Here goes your image URL</summary>
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class InheritanceTestController : ApiController
    {
        public ImageFeature Get([FromUri]ImageFeature imageFeature)
        {
            return imageFeature;
        }

        public ImageFeature Post(ImageFeature imageFeature)
        {
            return imageFeature;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific for Request Models .Possible option is to write an Operation filter

Here's the pseudo code

```
    public class RequestModelExtentionOperator: IOperationFilter    
        {                 
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.operationId == "Controller_ActionName")  // controller and action name
        {
           var refSchema = schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(typeof(List<ImageFeature>));
                //here you can create a new Parameter of type Array
var param=new Parameter 
                    {
                        name = "Features",
                        @in = "formData",
                        required = true,
                        type = "array"
                    };
            param.PopulateFrom(schema);
operation.parameters = new[]{ param };
        }
    }            
            }
    }
```

Then we can set the OperationFilter

```
httpConfiguration
     .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))
         {
             c.OperationFilter<RequestModelExtentionOperator>();
         });
```

Hope it helps