# Add Custom Model Classes to Swagger Documentation

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have classes in my API that are not request or response objects.  Is there a way within Swashbuckle version 5 that I can add these classes into the generated documentation (ideally in the Models section).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Swashbuckle for Asp.net core how can I add a model to the generated model list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006079/using-swashbuckle-for-asp-net-core-how-can-i-add-a-model-to-the-generated-model)

Comment: That would be exactly what I need however I am using v5 of swagger (sorry should have said in original question) do you know how this would be done in v5?