# Abstract classes on client generated code from swagger spec API net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, apiclient

I have an issue with my errors base class on my api. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397349/how-do-i-include-subclasses-in-swagger-api-documentation-using-swashbuckle) options to see it working on documentation. But when I use the swagger json to generate Rest Code on [https://editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/) it generates the 3 classes, BaseException (abstract), Error and Warning. when I use the respective code, on my responses comes a list of BaseException but always show me the base only information

```
exceptions:[
    {
      "severity": "Warning",
      "message": "warning message"
    },
    {
      "severity": "Error",
      "message": "testing"
    }
]
```

and if I put it as abstract

```
[DataContract]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "BaseException")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(ErrorData), "Error")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(WarningData), "Warning")]
    public abstract class BaseException : IEquatable<BaseException>
    {
```

another exceptions is raised:

```
Could not create an instance of type Api.Test.Client.Model.BaseException. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'severity', line 488, position 17.
```

I tried to maintain the generated class structure but with no luck, because always return the BaseException content and the discriminator on classes are null (I don't know why)

how can I fix this?
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `JsonConverter` attribute should be the discriminator field, in you JSON sample it should be `severity` so the `BaseException` class should be defined this way:

```
[DataContract]
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "severity")]
[JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(ErrorData), "Error")]
[JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(WarningData), "Warning")]
public abstract class BaseException : IEquatable<BaseException>
{
```

See documentation at : https://manuc66.github.io/JsonSubTypes/