# How to force NSwag and ng-swagger-gen to generate child class property in interface

Tags: angular, rest, swagger, swagger-codegen, nswag

I use [NSwag](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSwag.AspNetCore) to generate swagger document in .net core API and [ng-swagger-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-swagger-gen) for Angular client. The problem is that the generated interfaces ignore child class properties. 
See this example:

```
  //Backend classes
   public class Student:User{
        public DateTime EnrollDate{get;set;}
   }
   public class User {
      public string UserName{get;set;}
   }
```

and the client interfaces are

```
  export interface User{
   username:string
  }
  export interface Student extends User{
  }
```

as you can see, the `EnrollDate` property is ignored. Note that there's no `SwaggerIgnore` annotation on this property. How to solve this issue? how do I force Nswag or ng-swagger-gen to generate child properties?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397349/how-do-i-include-subclasses-in-swagger-api-documentation-openapi-specification

Comment: thank you but I passed to NSwag.AspNetCore Version="13.1.6" and the issue was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you but I updated to from version `11.18.7` to NSwag.AspNetCore Version="13.1.6" and the issue was solved!