# Multiple response type for an endpoint

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, openapi

I have an endpoint to query details about a "person". Problem, the response could be of type "PhysicalPerson" or "LegalPerson". Both inherit the same "BasePerson" class.

Here is my current code:

```
[HttpGet("personne/{idpersonne}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PersonneMoraleType), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PersonnePhysiqueType), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetPerson(string idpersonne, [FromQuery] bool avecDocuments = false)
{
    return Ok(await _app.LraConnector.LirePersonne(idpersonne, avecDocuments));
}
```

Problem, swagger only describe the second type (physical), but if I answer a LegalPerson, it throw a scheme exception.
If I use the "BasePerson", both answers works fine, but it's not described properly.

Is there something I can do to improve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include subclasses in Swagger API documentation/ OpenAPI specification using Swashbuckle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397349/how-do-i-include-subclasses-in-swagger-api-documentation-openapi-specification)

Comment: This isn't supported because it doesn't adhere to REST. You're essentially creating an endpoint that returns multiple different resource types. The fact that they all inherit from a common base class is inconsequential. `GetPerson` should return some generic person. If you need a specific person type, then you should have separate endpoints specifically for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported by swagger because iirc the responses is a dictionary with the statuscode as the key.

If you change one of the responses to return anything else than OK, then it will return your model.

However I dont think this is what you want. You could create one model like this:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public PhysicalPerson PhysicalPerson { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public OtherPerson OtherPerson { get; set; }
}
```

And then bind you data to the correct property and return this object as the 200 response.

Comment: This is clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this today and came across this: https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/.

Essentially, you can add multiple `SwaggerResponse` decorators to your controller method for multiple types, even with the same Http status code. This worked for me.